# Access a variable defined in a CommonJS library from the global browser scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, commonjs, browserify-shim

I have a "browserified" library which defines some React components, which I would like to load from an HTML page (served from a Rails app), and then instanciate the React components, fed by some data put inside the page by Rails.

*(The big picture is: we have a TurboLinks app, and we want to use some React components for very specific parts, needing more reactivity.
The Rails page would so load both React runtime & the needed applicative components lib, and then generate minimal raw JS to instanciate the React component as needed)*

All I found were ways to expose external libs variables to *my* lib, but I would like to expose ***my*** variables to global browser scope.

I ended up by exporting the classes in a rather ugly way (`window.Stuff = Stuff;`) directly from the `.jsx` source file, but I feel like this code is smelling...

Any suggestion on a better way to achieve such thing?

Comment: I think you should edit out references to `symbol` in your question. That makes me think of JS `Symbol`. I think you are using it to mean something like "module name".

Comment: Done. Thanks for the remark :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either expose the modules in your browserify bundle, e.g.:

```js
browserify()
  .require('./whatever', {expose: 'whatever'})
```

Then from the Rails page JS:

```js
require('whatever');
```

Or:

Create a standalone browserify bundle something like this:

```js
browserify('./entry', {standalone: 'something'})
```

`entry.js`

```
module.exports = {
  whatever: require('./whatever')
};
```

Then from the Rails page JS:

```js
window.something.whatever;
```

Comment: Great! The `standalone` option worked like a charm... Thank you very much!